# Trying to Create a Class that calculates the area of a Circle, output not what I'd like it to be

Tags: java, class

Trying to Create a Class that calculates the area of a Circle, output not what I'd lie it to be.
Every time user inputs a radius using the scanner, the output display 0.0.
What am I doing wrong?

```
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.Scanner;

    //Circle Class
    class Circle {
        double radius;

        double calculateArea; {
            double area = 3.14 * radius * radius;
        }
    }

//Object
public class test {
public static void main (String [] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("This program calculates the area of a circle.");
    System.out.println("\nEnter the radius of the circle and we wil do the rest!");

    Circle  c1 = new Circle ();
    c1.radius = input.nextDouble();
   System.out.println();

   System.out.println("The area of your desired circle is: ");
   System.out.println(c1.calculateArea);

  }
}
```

Comment: The syntax for a method declaration is `double calculateArea()`, not `double calculateArea;`.

Comment: Please make sure your code compiles before publishing it.

Comment: @Arkadiy it compiles, but that's quite an accident. calculateArea is a field. And the code inside the curly braces is an initialization block.

Comment: @JBNizet ouch, ouch, ouch!

Answer (score 0):

`calculateArea` and `area` are not recalculated when you set radius. You should make calculateArea into a method.

```
//Circle Class
class Circle {
    double radius;

    double calculateArea() {
        return 3.14 * radius * radius;
    }
}
```

Then when you want the area, call `circle.calculateArea()`.

Comment: that's what I'm attempting to do, how would I make calculateArea into a method?

Comment: Added an example implementation

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to use private attributes without setters or constructors.
Try this one

```
class Circle {
    double radius;

    public Circle(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return 3.14 * this.radius * this.radius;
    }
}
```

And use it as

```
Circle circle = new Circle(input.nextDouble());
System.out.println(circle.getRadius());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should rather define calculatearea as a method and not a simple field as you defined it. You should rather make it something like:

```
double calculateArea() {
        return 3.14 * radius * radius;
}
```

Then your program will work. Here is a complete example directly based on your sample with the exception that I am not using a separate test class but included the main method directly in the Circle class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Circle {

    double radius;

    double calculateArea() {
        return 3.14 * radius * radius;
    }

    public static void main (String [] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("This program calculates the area of a circle.");
        System.out.println("\nEnter the radius of the circle and we wil do the rest!");

        Circle  c1 = new Circle ();
        c1.radius = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("The area of your desired circle is: ");
        System.out.println(c1.calculateArea());

    }
}
```

**Illustration:**
[image]